# call back functions in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using Jquery function to upload a file. after upload it am taking filename. but filename is always coming empty. if I use F12(Inspect elements) then filename is coming. so how to get filename by using call back functions.
Here my code

```
    $('.inputfileLabel').click(function () {

    $(this).prev('input:file').trigger('click');
    debugger;

    var validExtensions = ['zip']; //array of valid extensions
    var fileName = $(this).prev('input:file').val();
    var fileNameExt = fileName.substr(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
    if ($.inArray(fileNameExt, validExtensions) == -1) {
        alert("Invalid file type");
        $(this).val("");
    }       
});
```

Comment: I can't see a callback function in that code. There's an onclick event, and a triggered click event, but no callbacks. Please try to make it clearer what you're trying to achieve, if you can.

Comment: You need a change handler on the `<input>`. You are trying to access file info before user has selected a file

Comment: Thanks  charlietfl, Actually I am new for web Technology, I don't know about call back functions, but I heard that through call-back function I can solve my problem. so please explain me how can I achieve it for my code.